# How to find where the variable come from in a bash set command?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

It happens I have some unwanted environment variable inside the `set` command output, and I can't get rid of these:

```
$ set
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:10010/
.... (lots of environment variables)
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:10010/
https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:11000/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16,172.16.0.0/12
socks_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:10010/
.... (some functions I have no idea where they come from)
.... (some functions from my .bashrc)
```

How could I find where these definition come from?

And these variables are also set for `root` user.

I have tried to unset these value and call bash (nested), they just keep coming back.

<strike>I have checked they are not in</strike> DO check common places listed in:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

And had no luck with:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37649308/7706652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO check common places listed in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Finally I found I have these variable configured in `/etc/environment` and have no idea why/when the program had the root privilege to update the file. (I always use `sudo` with caution.)

Answer (score 0):

To find out what Bash does as it starts:

`$ man bash` then hit `/` and type `startup`, then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

hit `n` to find next instance of `startup` (or `p` to go back to a previous one).
`h` will tell you about more keys.

Among the things in there you find wording that says it looks into e.g. `/etc/profile` depending on how it is started.

Happy hunting!